# what is the best technique to encrypt any document before storing (uploading) on IPFS?

Tags: web3j, ipfs, cryptography, public-key, encryption

I want to encrypt document before uploading to IPFS and enable more than user to decrypt it and note that the number of users may increase or decrease in any time?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [lit protocol](https://litprotocol.com/), you can encrypt before uploading and then decide how can decrypt it. Everyone can download it but it will be encrypted.

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a cryptographic challenge: In Assymentric cryptography (Public-key cryptography) you encrypt a file with the public key of one individual, so only the private key of that individual will be able to decrypt the file (1-1 encryption/decryption).

> TL;DR: Generate a data-key pair, encrypt the private part with the
> public key of all users that have write access, encrypt the public
> part with the public key of all users that have read access.

For more details, check this question, and its main answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91704/which-strategy-to-encrypt-data-accessed-by-multiple-users